# SDS-PAGE compared to western blotting

Tags: biochemistry

SDS-PAGE and western blotting are both used to separate and isolate proteins. My question is, which technique should be used when? Does one of them has advantages over the other one?

Comment: Blotting sits on top of SDS-PAGE, so it really depends on the question of your research which one you do...

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions. Your premise is incorrect.